# What do all the * do in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, symbols, align

Stars *, you see them everywhere

```
\hspace*{9001cm}

\begin{align*}

\leftmargin = *

\begin{flalign*}
```

Does anyone have a comprehensive guide as to what do all these * do in Latex? Or can you categorize most of their functionalities, e.g., equation bracket suppression

Comment: Generally speaking `\foo*` is just a variant of the macro `\foo` and similarly `\begin{goo*}...\end{goo*}` is a variant of `\begin{goo}...\end{goo}`. There are no hard and fast rules as to how this starred variant differs from the unstarred base command. That's completely up to the author of the macro/environment. In theory `\foo` and `\foo*` could do completely different things. ...

Comment: ... For some classes of commands there are general rules for what starred variants (usually) do. For example the starred version of the sectioning commands (`\section*`, `\chapter*`) produce unnumbered sections. The starred version of display math environments (`equation*`, `align*`) produce unnumbered lines of equations.

Comment: The third example is different from the other three, because in `\leftmargin = *` the `*` does not modify the command name (or is part of the command name), here you just assign the value `*`. Macros that work with `\leftmargin` will then need code to deal with the value `*`. Again, there are no hard and fast rules, but generally here I'd expect `*` to mean that the value is computed automatically from other values. (That's the case for `*` length assignments in `enumitem` I think).

Comment: `\hspace` , `\begin` and `\leftmargin` all have an `e` but you don't ask what is the special significance of `e`

Comment: Actually, this is more tradition than function.  One could create environments where the starred versions have nothing to do with the unstarred versions.  OTOH, starred versions of macros at least have the same arguments, but will a little effort one could overcome that restriction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

align* and flalign* --suppresses numbering

leftmargin=*  --- assign default value

hspace* -- a space that will not disappear at a  line break